# Is it Possible to Create temporary directory & store temporary images on Client Side?

Tags: java

I am new to Java & i am trying to make a Web Application which can access Client Images ,
so firstly i want to know that is it possible to create a folder in Clients temporary directory or in other drive and keep my temporary images their.

**Please help me to understand the possibility of what i am trying to make.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. And it has nothing to do with JavaEE.

Comment: How brother? please tell me i really need to know this..

Answer (score 1):

You need applets.

Here is some thread which gives some code of applet like one you need.

https://community.oracle.com/message/9960696#9960696

There are also some problems which author of this topic has and their resolutions.

Here is some tutorial on youtube just to start (I'm not sure if this is up to date): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDDeoqKcnGc

And tutorial from Oracle's page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Good luck

PS. Spring and java-ee has nothing to do with your problem since it is server side. You need client side solution. Applets or Flash or Silverlight or ...

Comment: Hey @zimi, thanks for your answer but i know this will be possible in applets but i want to make sure if their is any way to do this without applets.

Comment: There is diffrence between server side and client side. Server side as name indicates is on server. Server has no right to client resource such as disk. That's why this is impossible to do it with Spring or Java EE. You need client side solution. As I've wrote in answer: Applet, Flash, Silverlight or any other plugin which gives you more privilege in browser. So if you ask if there is other way: in Java no, only applets.